# Why Switch is not showing on older Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-switch

So switch that I made is showing normally on Android 8, but on Android 4.x is just invisible. What can I do to make it visible ?

```
<Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch_animacja"
        android:layout_width="49dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb"
        android:track="@drawable/switch_track"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.47"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tekst_animacja"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.37"
        android:showText="true"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
```

Comment: please share a broader context of the view

Comment: how is the text and the constraintlayout defined?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with "SwitchCompat" component ?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/switch_animacja"
        android:layout_width="49dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb"
        android:track="@drawable/switch_track"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.47"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tekst_animacja"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.37"
        android:showText="true"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
```

Switch has some different UI depending on API version :

[image]

Comment: Yes, but when I use it I get some gray rectangle and my app crashes.

https://i.imgur.com/REpkPr6.png

Comment: Check if when using switchCompat youre using from androidx instead of the old support library
"androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat" -> use this one
"android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat" -> not this one
if your project is already migrated to androidx

Comment: Did you use appcompat for ur project ? In your gradle file : implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$androidSupportVersion" and
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$androidSupportVersion"

Comment: I think so, here my gradle file:

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'